# Does Chrome run in separate processes/sandboxes?

Tags: chrome-for-android, sandboxing

On Windows/macOS Chrome runs in separate sandboxes to prevent the whole application from crashing mostly.

This does theoretically use more memory.

I have not been able to establish how this works on Android.  It seems to use one RAM slot from what I have gathered.

I was hopefully that it separated them into separate processes like on the PC so that Android can dispose of unused apps when aren't using them to save RAM usage.  It may just be my phone but it appears to get slower the more tabs I have open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Chrome runs in separate processes on Android.

This is what I get from `ps -aux | grep chrome` in a root Termux session:

```
u0_a128  14180  5.5  2.2 1530600 175948 ?      Sl   13:04   3:55 com.android.chrome
u0_a128  14418  2.2  1.0 1412520 84168 ?       Sl   13:06   1:31 com.android.chrome:privileged_process0
u0_i9    21115  3.0  1.1 1428008 91124 ?       Sl   14:07   0:13 com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process6
u0_i14   22492 16.2  1.2 1548252 100956 ?      Sl   14:14   0:13 com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process11
root     22686  0.0  0.0   8748  1524 pts/2    S+   14:15   0:00 grep --color=auto chrome
```

Comment: So why does it get slower with the more tabs I have open?

Comment: @William More RAM consumption, CPU time occupation, etc.

Comment: So why does switching to another browser suddenly work fine?  I actually have multiple browsers installed on my phone and after opening 10+ tabs in 1 browser I open 10+ in another browser and so on.  Each browser is much faster simple because it is a different browser(my assumption).

Comment: @William That's some implementstion details that only the dev team of each browser know.